# How can I test to be sure my wifi access point is failing?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android

I have a [Logitech wifi router](http://www.logitec.co.jp/products/wlan/lanw150nap/), with just one LAN and one WAN input. I hook it up to my cable router to create a wifi access on my LAN. I have a laptop (running Ubuntu), an Android tablet, an Android phone, and also various friends use my network when they are over, usually with an iPhone. It's possible I might have up to 4 or 5 devices connected at any one time.

Recently, the wifi has been strange. My laptop drops its connection after being on a while. On my phone, when I use PocketCasts to download podcasts, it says I am not connected to the wifi, my friends say they can't connect, etc. I also think video playback on my tablet might be hindered by lower transmission rates, as I feel it was a lot smoother before. It's hard to encapsulate the problem into definite descriptions because the problems come and go inconsistently.

I believe my wifi router might be failing, but because the symptoms are so varied, it's hard to be confident. My only rational for blaming the wifi router is that it seems unlikely that every device I connect by wifi are all having simultaneous failures.

Before I commit to buying a new router, is there any kind of test I can run on the device or between devices to verify the operating condition of my wifi router?

I can access the router via a web interface on my browser, but it doesn't seem to offer any internal testing mechanisms.

Comment: Have you considered using [inSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/)?

Comment: @Vinayak, thank you for responding. I hadn't heard of inSSIDer until you mentioned it now. It looks like a useful tool... but, at 20 US$, that's 2/3 of the price of just buying a new router (where I could potentially increase my speeds). It's tempting, but it would be ideal to be able to test for free so that I could use my money toward a new router if needed.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this looks like a [trial version of inSSIDer for office networks](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-IP-Scanner/InSSIDer.shtml). There are a few alternatives (some of them free) available [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/inssider/)

Comment: @Vinayak, nice! I will check those out. Thanks for providing the links.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that a neighbor has a wifi router on the same channel as yours. If his router has a transmit power higher than the transmit power of your router, then his signal is overshadowing yours.

A wifi scanner on your ubuntu laptop can give you graphical description of the existing wifis around you with power and channel parameters.

If you find that it is happening you have to change the channel on your router to a less busy one.